# Android Activity: Where to initialize parameters?

Tags: android, constructor, initialization, activity-lifecycle

I have some variables which must be initialized only once durign activity life-cycle.
If I initialize them inside `OnCreate` method, like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
}
```

initialization process happens every time which there are some configuration changes like screen rotation and etc since they will call `OnCreate` again and again.

I'm not going to disable configuration changes like screen rotation to fix this but I want to know where to place my initialization which initialization happens only once during activity life cycle.

Comment: Why not have a method that runs only once? Store a tag in your preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> initialization process happens every time which there are some configuration changes like screen rotation and etc since they will call OnCreate again and again.

That is because it is a new activity instance. By default, any fields will be `null` if you do not initialize them.

You are welcome to use the saved instance state `Bundle`, retained fragments, or other techniques to hold onto that data.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am thinking you could do:

```
//create a method to run once;

private void initParameters(){

   //do your thing here
}
```

Next, create a method to set a tag inside preferences

```
private void updatePreferences(){
  //now set a tag that indicates that params have been initialized

  ....
}
```

Now, inside `onCreate` or `onResume`,

```
//check prefernces
if(!initialized){
   //init here your params!
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea!